# JavaScript - Is it a bad practice to override a function by adding it to the last loaded external script?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that is triggered when clicking a button that is included in a partial view that is common to all pages of the website. What I would like is, when I'm on page "D" the function has to perform a different operation. What's the best practice to do that?

What I tried was to add a second external script for that page and include the function with the same name but different operations, then call the script AFTER the main script.

Partial View

```
<button id="btnSubmit" onclick="buttonClicked()"> Submit </button>
```

When I'm on pages "A", "B", "C", the function have to perform like this:

```
//JavaScript common file across all 3 pages:
function buttonClicked()
{
console.log(5);
}
```

When I'm on page "D" the function have to perform like this:

```
//JavaScript new file that is only used on Page D:
function buttonClicked()
{
console.log(10);
}
```

This is just a simple example. The functionality is much more complex and the website is already operational . Is this a bad practice? Right now it works fine, but is it possible that it will cause any issues(e.g different browsers)?

Thanks

Comment: It's not an ideal, but you shouldn't have any issues with different browsers.  I've seen plenty of frameworks use this idea too.  So your not alone.

Answer (score 2):

It will work but when you write more and more javascrpit code in your html-file it will get messy.
- Make a file called script.js
- Link the script.js file in your html-document (should be pretty easy to google)
- Make all the functions in the script.js file

Instead of using "onclick="buttonClicked()". Try to use (in script.js file):

```
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", your_funcion_name);
your_function_name(){ Write your function-code here }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a standard practice that is why a service is being created where you can call the function on different pages. Now you can't attached anything to the primary function without affecting your other pages when called.